# CanCan: как ограничить доступ к экшену?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

В Ability.rb ограничение накладывается над действиями в модели. А как ограничить доступ к экшенам контроллера?

Answer (score 2):

CanCan ограничивает доступ именно к action'ам контроллеров. Есть другой проект, [heimdallr](https://github.com/roundlake/heimdallr), который ограничивает доступ именно при доступе к модели.

**Пример для CanCan**

ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    return if user.nil?

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
      # ...
    end

    if user.role? :moderator
      can :manage, Post
      can :index, User
      # ...
    end

    # user
    can :create, Post
    # ...
 end
```

контроллер:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    authorize! :index, Post
    # ...
  end
end
```

и, RTFM

Answer (score 1):

[before_filter](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/22-use-before_filter)?
Вот [здесь](http://programming-in-example.blogspot.com/2012/04/rails-autocomplete.html) есть что то похожее, оно?:

```
#models.ability.rb
def initialize(user)
 #код

   if user.role?(:user)
        can :get_tags, Post

 #код
end
...
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
  #....

   post :get_tags, :on => :collection
end
```

Вы честно не пользовались поиском, или не можете понять что искать?

Вот начал [читать](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/) про канкан, всё намного интереснее. 
Похоже что в рамках идеологии канкана без костылей не получиться правильно ограничить доступ к акшену.

Вам точно надо это делать через канкан?

**UPD**
Хотя [это](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions) вроде то что надо, хотя не вижу тут принципиального отличия от before_filter

Comment: Нужно ограничить по ролям, фильтр не пойдет, нужно через Ability.rb

Comment: Так дело в том что для ограничения надо создать ресурс для контроллера и модель для ресурса, а мне нужно ограничить к контроллеру не имеющего ресурса (в роутинге) и модели.

Думаю что придется использовать встроенную функцию devise для ограничения в контроллерах использовать, а хотелось что бы всеми доступами из одного файла контролировать.

P.S Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В cancan по умолчанию накладывается ограничение на экшны контроллера, который завязан на модель (RESTful архитектура), поэтому класс, либо экземпляр класса используются для авторизации.
Поскольку в рассматриваемом случае не используется RESTful парадигма, то надо объявить доступ в Ability и авторизовать его в контроллере:

```
#ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    can :read, :home if user.has_role?(:home_reader)
  end
end

# home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    authorize! :read, :home
  end 
end
```